# Access GNU object file

Tags: gcc, arm

I have a C file with some structs. Currently I can access the structs using one public symbol `pub`.

```
char sym_001[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
char sym_002[] = { 3,4,5 };
char sym_003[] = { 0,8,15 };
struct _info { int n; char*a } info[] = {
   { 5, &sym_001 },
   { 3, &sym_002 },
   { 3, &sym_003 }
};
typedef struct pat { int a,b; struct _info*i; struct _pat*p } pat;
pat pat1 = { 3, 4, &info[2], 0 };
pat pat2 = { 3, 4, &info[0], &pat1 };
// 
struct { int property; pat*p } pub = { 1, &pat2 };
```

I need to serialize to a stream and deserialize the stream back to a memory layout. One problem are the addresses that need to replaced somehow with an offset in the stream and restored with the new address at the target. But this isn't the real challenge.

While serialization shouldn't be a problem I want to access to compiler output itself. I would prefer to avoid linking my serializer with the object file because there are a lot of such data files to process. Is there a convenient way to access the GNU binaries?

I have tried to use objcopy:

```
objcopy -I elf32-littlearm -O binary DS-Digital8.o foo.bin
```

But this gives zero for all places where I expected an address (that needs relocation).

Comment: You will always have issue with *addresses* and binutils.  You could try an *offset*.  For instance in the `info` struct, use `((int)(&info - &sym_001))` and make things static.  Or use something like *protocol buffers*.  Serialization has lots of *caveats* and they have been thought through by others.  Endianess, compact representation, alignments, etc.

Comment: @artlessnoise Yes there are some serialization issues. These should be solve with the relocation data in the object file. But the question is how to access the object files to read the .rodata and .reloc sections.

Comment: Did you consider working at the C level, perhaps by customizing the GCC compiler handling it (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) ...) ?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear to me from the question.  See [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/libelf-0.8.13.README), and also the *gold* and Gnu *ld* sources.  As Basile suggests, you can use GCC plug-in's like [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/).

Comment: @artlessnoise I would Accept your comment if it would be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artless noise comment give the right hint. The [libelf](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf) library has a complete support to access the object file.